# I want to pass json data from my template to my view

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to pass a `JSON` object from a JavaScript function to a `django` view.

I am a beginner in `django` and do not have any idea how to do this.

in the template `create_proposal.html` I have a JavaScript function called `convertToJson` that looks like:

```
function convertToJson() {
            console.log("convert");
            var obj = $(".input-form").serializeToJSON({

            });

            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);

        }
```

and in my `views.py` file the function i am trying to receive the `json` object looks like:

```
def resultPage(request):

    return render(request, 'result.html')
```

I am trying to pass the `jsonString` variable in the JavaScript function to the python function `resultPage` in the `views.py`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `AJAX`

Comment: Is this a GET or a POST? What is the data and what do you want to happen on the front-end?

Comment: @Tserenjamts can you show an example please

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html i worked django long time ago so i forgot almost all of the details but you can utilize ajax request. if i remember it correctly get result from ajax using `request.AJAX` did the job for me.

Comment: @IainShelvington It's a POST and I do not want to do anything in the frontend I am going to pass the json object to another function in the result Page function